# Optimizing APK File Size in Flutter Projects: Implementing Dynamic Module Downloads

Tags: reactjs, flutter, dart, unity-game-engine, mvvm

I am currently working on a Flutter project and have noticed that the resulting APK file size is quite large when compiling it. I am considering the possibility of implementing a dynamic approach similar to that of many games, where not all the content is loaded initially, but rather elements are downloaded as the user needs them.

An example of this can be found in PUBG Mobile, where the default map is Erangel for the initial Battle Royale mode, but players have the option to download other maps such as Miramar, Sanhok, and Vikendi. Although this may increase the size of the game, it is not a mandatory download at the beginning, but a choice of the user.

In my project, I have noticed that there are modules that some users may not use. My goal is to offer the option to download only the modules that the user needs instead of including everything from the start. Since Flutter is a robust platform but can generate applications with a considerable size, I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to effectively implement this functionality

I tried using Unity or React with an MVVM architecture, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can create different flavors of your app.
Checkout this
https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants